# Pv Diagram of a pressure cooker

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, pressure, diagram

For a bit of self training in thermodynamics, I've been trying to think of some random systems and go ahead and try to solve them, some of these things I've stolen from random googling of university exams, while others I just considered. While perusing I found this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160114/can-a-liquid-boil-in-a-closed-container) over at physics that does some explaining, but is somewhat counter intiutive to how I understand how to use pv or pt diagrams.

So for an example, given a pressure cooker with a total volumn of 0.2m^3 that has been filled so that by a saturation point of p = 3bar has a steam content of x=0.5, with continued heating, the steam reaches fully dried state, x=1, at which pressure do we end up at, and how much heat is required?

The actual solutions of pressure and heat don't interest me as much as much as how one would draw this in a pv diagram?

My assumption was:

[image: diagram]

However, I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, especially when considering the description in the afformentioned link..However, I've always understood, once you enter the wet stream region, further heating or cooling always follows a specific isotherm/isobar, which isn't the case in the provided description over at physics.se